# temperature of each layer of a cooler

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

I have a cooler with five layers and I know the temperature outside and inside of the cooler. I created a Matlab model that demands me the temperature of each layer of the cooler.

I want to know how I can find the temperature of each layer(considering that I know their thermal resistance)

Can someone help me to find the temperature of each layer

Comment: Have you had freshman physics yet and, if so, did they cover heat conduction in the course?

Comment: Actually i am a High school student. But I know some thing about heat conduction

Comment: So you know that the temperature varies linearly with portion within each layer, and that the heat flow rates match at the boundaries between the layers.

Comment: I didn’t know that :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I find how to calculate the temperature of each layer 
[image]

Comment: I think that this image-only answer is bad for the same reasons that [we discourage image-only questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/44126). Please consider writing a proper answer.